# Categorizing Camel Route related Exceptions

Tags: exception, apache-camel

Im thinking of creating custom exceptions. So that all types of camel route exceptions are to be handled in Processor files. Could someone please answer what are the camel exceptions that might occur in camel routes, so that i can create custom exception hierarchy based my requirement..?

Answer (score 2):

Any kind of exception can be thrown during routing, eg a `java.lang.Throwable` as the super type.

If you do some IO work then `IOException` can be thrown, if you do SQL work, then `SQLException` can be thrown, and if you have code mistakes then `NullPointerException` etc.

Apache Camel may wrap exceptions in `org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException` with the current `Exchange` if it happens during routing and it was detected and rethrown by Camel.

Comment: Thanks for the information. small doubt about dead letter channel. im using a deadLetterChannel("jmstx:queue:ErrorHandler") in errorhandler. The Errorhandler JMS queue calls a processor. In My Processor the exception.getMessage() is null. what could be the reason....??

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-the-exception-null-when-i-use-onexception.html

Comment: At first this is my error handler: errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("jmstx:queue:ErrorHandler").maximumRedeliveries(1));  2nd im using Exception e=(Exception)exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT,Exception.class); eventhough exception is null.....